# cant access Disks after update and other problems

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, updates, hard-drive, data-recovery

I updated my laptop yesterday. after reboot

1. the desktop back to completely new ,even the wallpaper back to factory, files are still safe.
2. all keyboard shortcuts gone .
3. gnome terminal back to new and the profiles gone , but zsh is still connected .
4. the other windows disks are not visible and cant access them, but i can see them in the partition manager .
5. my secondary ubuntu partition not visible and cant access it .
6. system doesn't recognize external hard drive .

Note this is not the first problem i encounter in ubuntu after an update but this time is the worst , kindly i need help recover the data in my secondary disk .

thanks you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix the the access to the all disks and the external hard drive , by using the program ( disks ) and mounted them manually.